# How do I apply the definition of conditional expectation to get the answer I want?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X$ is a random exponential variable with $\lambda=1$ such that the PDF of $X$ is $f_X(x)=e^{-x}$.

Suppose $Y_1=min(X,t)$

What is the $E[X|Y_1=t]$?

Apparently the answer is $\frac{\int_{t}^{\infty}xe^{-x}dx}{  \int_{t}^{\infty} e^{-x}dx }$ but why ?

The definition of conditional expectation as I understand it is as follows:

$E[X|Y_1=t] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y1}(x|y_1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\frac{f_{X,Y1}(x,y_1)}{f_{Y_1}(y1)}dx$

How do I apply the textbook formula for conditional expectation to get the answer above?

Comment: In recent times, this specific problem has been asked here again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first you've got to think about
$$
P(Y_1=t).
$$

$$
P(Y_1= t)=P(min(X,t)=t)=P(X>t)=\int_t^\infty{e^{-x}}dx
$$

And by following your idea, you'll get the answer

Comment: Yes, this is how you get the denominator of the fraction.  But how do you get the numerator? The numerator looks a lot like the definition of expectation, except bounded by X > t. Is that pretty much it? The numerator is just the expected value for the bound that we care about?

Comment: The numerator is an integration of joint pdf of X and Y.
This pdf is conditioned Y=t so you only have to integrate from t to infinity.